# How to redirect to a brand new route with history push?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, history

I'm using `props.history.push('/something')`
from a route `'/test'`

but then I'm redirected to `'/test/something'` instead of `'/something'` how can I make it happen?

Comment: are you using `props.history.push('/something')` or `props.history.push('something')`

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround I think if you create a redirect from one path to another then it will work.

Try as the following:

```
<Route exact path="/test/something">
    <Redirect to="/something" />
</Route>
```

So this way from `/test/something` it will redirect to `/something`.

I hope this helps!

Comment: is that the only way? it looks kinda hacky.

Comment: @AlexK With `history.push()` for this scenario I'm not aware of any other solution. Can you please test this one if it works for you?

Answer (score 0):

If you use **hashRouter**, then you can simply write like this.

```
this.props.history.push('#/something')
```